# Why Assets is in different name space depending of main activity or a class?

Tags: xamarin.android

If I am in the main activity, if I want to open a file that there is in the assets, I use this code:

```
using (Stream miFicheroOrigen = Assets.Open("configuration.xml"))
{}
```

I can see that the namespace is Android.Context.Res.AssetManager.

However, I would like to have a class with the methods to manage the configuration, so I have create this class:

```
internal class ConfigurationManager
{
}
```

But it this case I have to use Android.Content.Resoruces.System.Assets, i can't use the Assets in the same namespace than in the main activity.

It works, but I would like to know if really it is the same Assets or different.

Perhaps it is because the first one is an Activity and in the second one it is a normal class, but I don't understand well why in the second case I can't access to the same namespace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see that the namespace is Android.Context.Res.AssetManager.
>
> But it this case I have to use Android.Content.Resoruces.System.Assets

It may seem that you have mistyped the wrong letter in your question. Maybe you want to know the difference between them as bellow:

[Android.Content.Res.AssetManager Class](http://Android.Content.Res.AssetManager%20Class) **VS** [Android.Content.Res.Resources Class](http://Android.Content.Res.Resources%20Class)

**Different:**

`Android.Content.Res.AssetManager` : Provides access to an application's raw asset files; see [Resources](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Res.Resources/) for the way most applications will want to retrieve their resource data. This class presents a **lower-level API** that allows you to open and read raw files that have been bundled with the application as a simple stream of bytes.

`Android.Content.Res.Resources` : Class for accessing an application's resources. This sits on top of the asset manager of the application (accessible through Resources.Assets) and provides a **high-level API** for getting typed data from the assets.Using application resources makes it easy to update various characteristics of your application without modifying code, and—by providing sets of alternative resources—enables you to optimize your application for a variety of device configurations (such as for different languages and screen sizes). **This is an important aspect of developing Android applications that are compatible on different types of devices**.

`Android.Content.Res.Resources.System` Property : **Return a global shared Resources object** that provides access to only system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc).

**Same**:

They all can get the *Android.Content.Res.AssetManager*.

```
Android.Content.Res.AssetManager assetManager = Android.Content.Res.Resources.System.Assets;
```

**Result** :So you can see *Android.Content.Res.Resources.System* is a global shared resources object,so you can get from a normal class.However , it does not mean that *Android.Content.Res.AssetManager* can not be getted from normal class.According to the documentation, they are only the high and low points of the api, and the document recommends using such methods(*Android.Content.Res.Resources.System*) to obtain resources.